# How to get "available on backorder" text to show after some costumization of stock status in woo commerce

Tags: woocommerce, stock

I have some costumization for the stock status for my products in my woocommerce store.

It looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text', 99, 2 );
function bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
$stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $stock < 19 ) {
    if ($stock == 1) { 
  
    $availability = " " . $stock . " i lager";
}
return $availability;
}
```

The problem i have is that the "available on backorder text" is not showing when i use this code (when it is enabled in the products stock settings). Now it just says O in stock, so you miss that is possible to backorder the actual product.

So is it a way to get same display for stock status, and also the text "Out of stock" and (if enabled) "Available on backorder?"

I have tried to add this code, but it didnt change anything.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
    function filter_product_availability_text( $availability_text, $product ) {
    // Check if product status is on backorder
    if ($product->get_stock_status() === 'onbackorder') {
        $availability_text = __( 'Kan restnoteras', 'your-text-domain' );
    }
    return $availability_text;
    }
```

Would be happy if someone have a good advice here!

Comment: Why do you have the code block with the `$verb` variable if you don't use it in your first function?

Comment: Oups that should been removed! I have edit it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec

Thank you for the reply. I dont know what happened, but your code suggestion and my answer to it just disapeared?! Im sure i did not remove it.. 

However, for the cod you suggested, the backorder text did not show when the  product is set to be available on backorder. It just shows "0 in stock"  

But "ikke på lager" text is showing when option "no backorder" is set to the product or variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated - Try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_availability_text', 100, 2 );
function custom_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability = __('Ikke på lager', 'woocommerce' );
    } elseif ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $availability = $product->backorders_require_notification() ? __('Kan restnoteras', 'woocommerce' ) : '';
    } elseif ( ! $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $availability = __('Kan restnoteras', 'woocommerce' );
    } elseif ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        $availability = __( 'I lager', 'woocommerce' );
        $stock_amount = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        switch ( get_option( 'woocommerce_stock_format' ) ) {
            case 'low_amount':
                if ( $stock_amount <= wc_get_low_stock_amount( $product ) ) {
                    $availability = sprintf( __( 'Bare %s igjen på lager' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $stock_amount, $product ) );
                }
                break;
            case '':
                $availability = sprintf( __( '%s i lager', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $stock_amount, $product ) );
                break;
        }
        if ( $product->backorders_allowed() && $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
            $availability .= ' ' . __( '(kan restbestilles)', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    } else {
        $availability = '';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
When i try that, "Ikke på lager" Shows up when stock is 0 and product is set to be not on back order. 
But when the product is set to "available on back order" it just shows "0 in stock". and not the text "kan restnoteras".

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately no stock status at all is showing when trying it on the site.  :/

Comment: Oups! you are right… I removed the last line unintentionally. I have updated my code.

Comment: Ok, i changed some settings in the shop and now it looks like it works with the code :D
Thank you, you are a star!